# Why does this function return undefined, even though the variable exists?

Tags: javascript, function, return, undefined

I've tried to `console.log()` pretty much everything at this point. There's probably a simple reason that I'm missing, but I really can't put my mind on it. Here is the code:

```
const primes = [];

//Function to determine if a number is prime
function isPrime(num) {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++)
        if (num % i === 0 && num > 1) return false;
    return true;
}

//Cycling through the number up until 100 and adding the primes to the array
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) primes.push(i);
}

let min = 0, max = primes.length;

//Binary search algorithm
function binarySearch(array, target) {
    let guess = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);

    if (array[guess] === target) return guess;

    if (array[guess] < target) min = guess + 1;
    else max = guess - 1;

    binarySearch(array,target);
}

console.log(binarySearch(primes, 3));
```

I don't understand why i get undefined as the output even though there is a return function that is supposed to return the variable guess.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are getting `undefined` because you forgot to return from `binarySearch` function.

Try as the following:

```
function binarySearch(array, target) {
    // ... implementation

    return binarySearch(array,target);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! So much headache and it was as simple as that; anyways, thanks for saving me a lot more headache!